# Is there a relation between DFA and Loop, NFA and recursion?

Tags: finite-automata, automata-theory

I have heard that DFA can be simulated by Loop and NFA can be simulated by recursive method. I don't understand how that works. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: no any relation between DFA & loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sense, sure. DFAs can easily be simulated by writing a `do...while` loop with a `switch` statement in it based on the current state, whereas you can think of a simulator for NFAs as doing a search on a tree (depth first search is recursive, although you could just as well imagine a breadth-first search). There's not really any formality in this, just a casual observation about how you might implement simulators.